# Responsive flexible images not working

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, flexibility

I'm trying to make my website responsive. I found on this website (http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/) that to be able to make images flexible, you have to use max-width: 100%.

Which I did on my website (http://riksblog.com/Marnik/index.html) for #promo1img (the first iphone image) but as you can see, it's not working as it should.

Which css-styles am I missing?

Comment: Remove `min-height: auto` from `section.first` class and add `height:auto`.  As for mobile screen sizes, your image is responsive but `h1` and `.contactemailp` are not.

Comment: Do I need to add height:auto to section.first or #promo1img ?

Regarding making h1 and .contactemailp responsive, I found on this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25403510/bootstrap-3-responsive-h1-tag) that I should use:

h1{
     word-wrap: break-word;
     -webkit-hyphens: auto;
     -moz-hyphens: auto;
     -ms-hyphens: auto;
     -o-hyphens: auto;
     hyphens: auto;
}

Is that a right solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `section.first` class to below: (line 110, in stijl css file):

```
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url(../img/header.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
```

The above code fixes the background cover image.

Now there are other elements in the html that are not responsive. So for those, add this codes to your css:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
    #contactemailp{
        margin-left:0px;
    }
    section.first .section-content .section-content-inner h1 {
        font-size: 40px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, yakutsa. 

I'm using a few other images, to make them responsive/flexible, I should add the same style like the section.first?

So width: 100%; and  height: auto; to get them flexible and resize?

Comment: @MarnikBruyndonckx, make sure that the width of the surronded div of your image is `width:100%` and give the `img` class `width:100%`. That way, you won't see any flow all screen sizes.

Comment: For some reason, the image is really huge, it's like it expands a lot over the whole body when using width: 100%. For example the first iphone mockup is called #promo1img and the surrounded div is called section.promote1. CSS styles: section.promote1 {
    margin-top: 0;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    width: 100%
} and #promo1img {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 200px;

} the image is now spread over the whole body with very bad resolution, it's like it's zooming in instead of using the original height and width of the image

Comment: @MarnikBruyndonckx, I see your point. Then inside of your `@media screen and (max-width: 480px)` code, change the class `#promo1img` your `height:auto` to `height:270px`. It should re-size your image without any distort.